# Why is the network tab empty in developer tools when using a meteor app website?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, http, firefox, meteor

When using a website containing a meteor app (for example https://edabit.com), I notice that almost nothing shows up in the network tab of firefox or chrome in the developer tools. For example, when logging to the website, no new request shows up when pressing the "sign in" button after filling my details. This is true whether I input a correct or incorrect password (which obviously needs to be sent to the server through some kind of request to be checked).

If I use the "meteor devtools" extension for chrome, I can see method calls in the new "meteor" tab ("calling method login with [object Object]" for example). But my question is more theoretical: how is meteor "hiding" from the developer tool here? Is there a way to make the actual requests show up?

(I am learning about http requests using the developer tools and the requests module in python. My goal is to automate some common tasks,like checking for new posts on a given topic. It's great that a specific extension exists for meteor, but if I have the same problem with a different app I will be stuck.)

Note: I am aware that I could use tcpdump or wireshark here, but I was hoping to keep using the developer tools or something similar instead (for the added context, the built-in filtering, the replay ability, the ui etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because lot of communication are made via Distributed Data Protocol (DDP).

See [Publications and Data Loading](https://guide.meteor.com/data-loading.html)

Comment: So from my understanding after skimming the documentation, DDP is it's own protocol, and is sent over websocket or socksjs. Websocket itself is its own protocol (distinct from HTTP), and is sent over TCP on port 443. The developer tools only look for HTTP requests and are therefore missing it.

Would you know what would be the best tool to use to see all TCP communication from a web app, to get an experience close to the developer tools?

Comment: [Meteor DevTools Evolved on Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/meteor-devtools-evolved/ibniinmoafhgbifjojidlagmggecmpgf)